# URL Re-writes and Google Indexing

Tags: url-rewriting, google-index

I was asked to perform some URL re-writes for a new site with numerous dynamic pages and this has all worked fine.

However when I look at the URLs that Google has indexed, it has indexed the 'non-rewrite' url, so all the '?', '&' etc are being used.

What do you have to do to force Google to index your re-written URLs?

I just assumed it would do this automatically and never expected it to be an issue.

All help is gratefully appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Steps 
1) Make sure that expired pages are no longer publicly accessible
2) Anything you do not wish Bots to crawl should be flagged with appropriate "nofollow" meta tags
3) Submit a new sitemap to your Google Web developer account
4) Make sure your Website throws a 404 error when a page isn't found.  It is always a good idea to make a splash page for a 404 error which links back to your home page. (this is accomplished different ways across different server-side languages)

Google will automatically remove indexed pages if they no longer exist.. So be patient.

Comment: Kevin thanks for your quick reply.  I'm a little confused by your answer, particularly your last sentence.  The pages do exist but Google is just calling them by the 'wrong' URL.  Wrong in the sense that it is not using my re-writes.  If you type in both URLs (non-rewrite and rewrite) they both take you to the same page.  My problem is not non-existent pages.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You simply need to submit a new sitemap to google.  Make sure that your sitemap only has "URL-friendly" urls and doesn't include they messy querystrings.  You have a problem, if they are valid URL's and they are already indexed, nothing you can do about it other than writing a script that blocks robots when the url accessed is not the url-friendly one.  What language is your server-side code?

Comment: Kevin, many thanks again.  Oh darn, so Google is stuck with those versions of the URL now and the new sitemap even though it contains our preferred format will not override it?  I am using PHP.  Do you know of any good tutorials to help me carry out the necessary work?